# How to exclude a twig partial from a base extend in Symfony on some pages only?

Tags: symfony, twig, extend, partial, radix

Is there a way to specify an "extend" in Twig to exclude one of its included partials ?

To better explain myself, here is my base.html.twig

```
<body>
        {% include '/main/_navbar.html.twig' %}
        {% block body %}
            {% for flashError in app.flashes('success') %}
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{ message }}</div> 
            {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% include '/main/_footer.html.twig' %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('script/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
```

On my login page, I do not need my `_navbar.html.twig` partial. Is there a way to **not include** (exclude) it knowing my view `extends` from this `base` template ? Are there any "options" I could pass behind that `extends` ?

This is the code I use to `extend` my base template on my login page :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: extends is always a bit tricky.  By far the easiest approach is to just have a duplicate base_no_navbar.html.twig template.  You could also just check inside the navbar template to see if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: @Cerad Very nice ideas, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the include you don't want to include in a seperate block, then override the block with empty content, e.g.

*base.html.twig*

```html
<body>
        {% block nav %}
            {% include '/main/_navbar.html.twig' %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% block body %}
            {% for flashError in app.flashes('success') %}
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">{{ message }}</div> 
            {% endfor %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% include '/main/_footer.html.twig' %}
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('script/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

*login.html.twig*

```html
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block nav %}{% endblock %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/o6n2bd)

Comment: Great ! So, just to be clear @DarkBee, we can name our blocks the way we want, or are they predefinied ?

Comment: Blocks can be named w/ever yes